# ios - generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes taking too long

Tags: ios, image, generator

The problem I have is loading 20 images from video takes too long. The more thumbnails I want to get, the longer I have to wait. Method I use is generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes. Does anyone know why I have this problem?

```
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){

    if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
    }

    UIImage *frameImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:im];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_frameImageView setImage:frameImage];
    });
};
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:timeArray completionHandler:handler];
```

Comment: I am having same issue, did you got any solution?

Comment: @ScorpianAlive facing same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know your issues.

It takes a lot of time for generating thumbnail because you set requestedTimeToleranceAfter and requestedTimeToleranceBefore are kCMTimeZero.

**Long Answer:**
If you specific TimeTolerance, it will be turned for precision rather than performance. if you just want to video thumbnail, so you don't need generate thumbnail with hight precision.

It's similar with seekToTime with tolerance. Reference from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW3 , Section Seeking—Repositioning the Playhead.

**Short Answer :**
Just remove requestedTimeToleranceAfter and requestedTimeToleranceBefore.